# VB Script excel marco used to work but now doesn't

Tags: excel, vba

```
'Delete All transaction rows from spreadsheet containing "Cash" in Column N
    Dim c As Range
    Dim SrchRng
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("N1", ActiveSheet.Range("N999").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("Cash", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
'Delete All transaction rows from spreadsheet containing "Account Type" in Column N
    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("N1", ActiveSheet.Range("N999").End(xlUp))
    Do
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("Account Type", LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
            Loop While Not c Is Nothing
```

Set `c = SrchRng.Find("Cash", LookIn:=xlValues)` line is now causing debug.  The data looks correct as there are lines in Column N that contain word Cash that should delete entire line.

Comment: what you mean is causing debug?

Comment: Get in the habit of using `Find()` method by explicitly specifying at least `LookIn` and `LookAt` parameters, since they all get used with their last assumptions, even if from Excel UI

Comment: I copied your code and it works as intended :D. What error are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting the following error:  Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: ‘Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch is still occuring.  Any ideas?